# How to implement angular style directives in backbone?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, backbone.js, underscore.js, underscore.js-templating

I am aware of this library https://github.com/berzniz/backbone.directives. However I wanted to know if there is a way of implementing angular style directives in backbone without using a library.(Maybe through underscore or backbone views)  My use case is that i want the the html inside the div tag to be visible only if the variable isVisible is true.

```
<div bb-show="isVisible">
   <h1>You can see this</h1>
</div>
```

Is there a way to achieve this through backbone?

Comment: I've used [rivets.js](http://rivetsjs.com/) in backbone projects for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Angular you have unique two-way data binding concept:

```
.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.isVisible = true;
    $scope.hide = function() {
        this.isVisible = false;
    }
})
```

The view has access to the model, and there are several ways of displaying model data in the view, one of them is to use **ng-show directive**:

```
ng-show="isVisible"
```

[AngularJS example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/woEdqj)

Backbone.js doesn’t do any data binding. But you can use underscore **template** method and pass in a data object that has properties corresponding to the template's free variables.:

```
this.$el.html(this.template({
    isVisible: this.condition
}));
```

And now your isVisible variable is available in your template. And if it is false it will not render HTML, otherwise it will.

```
<script id="myTemplate" type="text/template" >
    <% if(isVisible) { %>
    <div>
       <h1>You can see this</h1>
    </div>
    <% } %>
    <button class="js-hide">Hide</button>
</script>
```

[BackboneJS example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YpOVBE)

Answer (score 1):

*If you only want to hide a section on render depending on a variable value, check t_dom93's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41098831/1218980) about Underscore template.*

---

**Backbone is not a framework, it's a toolbox**. It doesn't do binding and doesn't even do rendering by itself. It uses jQuery for that by default and let it up to you to implement the binding however you like. So implementing two-way binding like angular without a lib would need the equivalent of writing your own lib, binding data with custom `data` attribute on HTML tag using jQuery.

---

## [Epoxy.js](http://epoxyjs.org/)

The closest I found that does this is Epoxy.js. It provides two-way binding like Stickit, but also filters, handlers, computed fields.

It is easy to integrate into an existing project. It's almost transparent and if you start to use it, you're **not obligated** to use it everywhere as both vanilla Backbone and Epoxy can co-exist.

### Binding examples

The `ng-show` behavior can be achieved with the [`toggle` handler](http://epoxyjs.org/documentation.html#handler-toggle) (one-way binding):

```
<div data-bind="toggle:modelAttribute">
    This is visible only if modelAttribute is truthy.
</div>
```

`ng-model` is the [`value` handler](http://epoxyjs.org/documentation.html#handler-value) (two-way binding) and can be combined with any other handler:

```
<input name="firstname" data-bind="value:firstname,events:['keydown']">
```

See [all the handlers](http://epoxyjs.org/documentation.html#binding-handlers).

### Computed attributes

> An Epoxy model introduces computed attributes, which operate as
>   accessors and mutators. A computed attribute will get an assembled
>   value derived from other model attributes, and will set one more more
>   mutated values back to the model. Computed attributes may be **get**
>   and **set** just like normal model attributes, and will trigger
>   `"change"` events on the model when modified, however they do not
>   exist within the model's `attributes` table, nor will they be saved
>   with model data.

```
var BindingModel = Backbone.Epoxy.Model.extend({
  defaults: {
    firstName: "Obi-Wan",
    lastName: "Kenobi"
  },
  computeds: {
    fullName: function() {
        return this.get("firstName") +" "+ this.get("lastName");
    }
  }
});

var view = new Backbone.Epoxy.View({
  el: "#app-computed",
  model: new BindingModel()
});
```

In the template

```
<div id="app-computed">
  <label>First:</label>
  <input type="text" data-bind="value:firstName,events:['keyup']">

  <label>Last:</label>
  <input type="text" data-bind="value:lastName,events:['keyup']">

  <b>Full Name:</b>
  <span data-bind="text:fullName"></span>
</div>
```

### Binding filters

> Epoxy tries to strike a balance between robust binding options and
>   clean binding definitions. While Epoxy uses a similar binding
>   technique to [Knockout.js](http://knockoutjs.com/), it intentionally discourages some of
>   Knockout's inline-javascript allowances.
>
> Instead, Epoxy provides filtering wrappers for formatting data
>   directly within your bindings. Notice how the `not()` and `format()`
>   filters are used in the following binding scheme:

```
<span data-bind="toggle:not(firstName)">Please enter a first name.</span>
```

See [all the filters](http://epoxyjs.org/documentation.html#binding-filters).

---

## [Knockback.js](http://kmalakoff.github.io/knockback/)

If you already like Knockout.js and you are missing some features with Backbone, Knockback.js is probably the best bet. They provide a quite complete documentation in both CoffeeScript and JS.

[image: Knockback.js features comparison]

## ViewModel and Observable

This is an additional step compared to Epoxy, which completely seperates the model from the bindings and computeds.

```
var model = new Backbone.Model({first_name: "Planet", last_name: "Earth"});

var ViewModel = function(model) {
  this.first_name = kb.observable(model, 'first_name');
  this.last_name = kb.observable(model, 'last_name');
  this.full_name = ko.computed((function() {return "" + (this.first_name()) + " " + (this.last_name());}), this);
};

var view_model = new ViewModel(model);

ko.applyBindings(view_model, $('#kb_observable')[0]);
```

The template binding is really similar:

```
<input data-bind="value: first_name, valueUpdate: 'keyup'" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Without a library, it's harder to achieve. I found stick.it of help with two way bindings: https://github.com/NYTimes/backbone.stickit

From their docs:

"Similar to `view.events`, you can define `view.bindings` to map selectors to binding configurations. The following bindings configuration will bind the `view.$('#title')` element to the `title` model attribute and the `view.$('#author')` element to the `authorName` model attribute:"

```
bindings: {
  '#title': 'title',
  '#author': 'authorName'
}
```